# Do you think this is the right way to rename a django app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-apps

I read different threads and tutorials on renaming and migrating a Django app ([How to rename a Django app and migrate data from an app to the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957167/how-to-rename-a-django-app-and-migrate-data-from-an-app-to-the-other) for instance), I also tried to use the django package called django-rename-app but it didn't work at all.

I'm going to explain the way I renamed my app in my development environment and I would like to know if you expect troubles, as apparently everything is working just as it did before so I'm considering doing the same in production.

Here are the steps I took inside my root project directory and my virtualenv activated, using Django 3.2:

#### Create the destination app

> django-admin startapp app2

#### Copy these files and directories

> cp app1/*.py app2/

> mkdir app2/templates

> mkdir app2/static

> cp app1/templates app2/templates

in this case I had a sub-folder named after the app so I renamed it like this

> mv app2/templates/app1 app2/templates/app2

> cp app1/static app2/static

### Models.py

Change the related_name attributes of all ForeignKeys in my new models.py and update all their references inside my views, admin, form and templates

### Make sure your apps won't imported by the same name

Look for the instanciation of an AppConfig class inside your app directory and if you find something like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AnunciosConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app1'
```

that's where you need to also change your app name from *app1* to *app2*

### Activate the new app

Add my app2 to the list of the enabled apps of settings.py

### Delete `__pycache__`

Find and delete or empty all the `__pycache__` directories in app2

### Migrations

this will not work until all the overlapping bits are corrected, so this is how I tested everything was ok (it will not be aware of URLs problem at this stage)

> python manage.py makemigrations

> python manage.py migrate

### Cloning data

Now I used the Django shell to migrate data from app1 to the app2

> python manage.py shell

> import app1

> from app2.models import *

So I will have to use "app1.ModelName" to refer to the old app and simply "ModelName" to address the new app2 instances

Then I use the [Models and QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) to just create new objects in app2 with for loops for each app1 instances, with a corresponding app2 object that is saved (this needs be written individually and depends on each situation)

### Deactivate the old app

Now I remove or comment out the old app1 reference in settings.py so that it is disabled

### Rename the directory

At this point I needed to rename the app1/ directory to something unknown to Django

> mv app1 app1_

### Deal with the new errors

It seems some more errors appeared here with URLS and Views, so I had to just update app1 references to app2 until they disappeared

### Delete Database table

Enter MySQL (in my case), and disable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS

> USE yourowndjangodatabase;

> SHOW TABLES;

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

so now I can delete them like this

> DROP TABLE app1__yourfirstmodel;

> DROP TABLE app1__yoursecondmodel;

and so on until none is left, then set the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS back to 1 so that it is enabled

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Like I saw here [Can't drop table: A foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100911/cant-drop-table-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

### CONCLUSION

And basically that was it, it worked perfectly for my development environment. I have a perfect copy of my previous app1 and web application that is just using app2 now.

I improvised so I'm not sure this is the right procedure but it worked so I would like to ask if you see any problem or suspect there will be issues in production.

Comment: I found a problem: when I run "python manage collectstatic" the directory created inside /static/ is still named after app1. I suspect it may have something to do with the virtualenvironment cache like I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I deleted and recreated the python virtualenvm even used different names, I also deleted all the __pycache__ dirs again but there still is a reference to app1 somewhere

Comment: So I edited the database table django_content_type where there still was a reference to app1, the models very tables had been deleted previously, deleted all the __pycache__ and also deleted all migration files. Recreated the virtualenv, but still "collectstatic" creates a folder called like app1. I'm using "grep -r" on the project root directory and it doesn't come up. Any idea where this name is retrieved from?

Comment: I even tried to create a clone of the project, import the apps folders and activate them, then migrate. I still see "collectstatic" create an "app1" folder inside /static so I suspect the problem may be elsewhere, maybe some python cache I have no access to

Comment: By "clone" I mean a new django project that I imported my apps in (already renamed)