# South backward migration can't find model

Tags: python, migration, django-south

I'm following this [very good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080790/871910) of transferring models. I've made a mistake and I want to perform a backwards migration. And I'm stuck.

In the backwards migration I'm changing a foreign key constraint with the following line:

```
db.alter_column('lab_scan', 'raw_file_id',
  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['lab.File']), null=True)
```

South complains that `The model 'file' from the app 'lab' is not available in this migration.`

The `models` dictionary, with the frozen models, does in fact contain an entry for `lab.file`. So I can't figure out what's wrong.

I tried using `orm['lab.file']` (with a lowercase f), just in case, and it improve matters.

UPDATE: Turns out `orm.models` is empty, even though my migration's `models` is not.